# undefined local variable or method capybara rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I keep getting this strange error when I use capybara methods outside of a before block:

```
$ rspec . -e "PasswordResets"
/spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<Class:0x00000003bfa100> (NameError)
```

`root_path` does exists. I have multiple other tests that work. But it appears I can only use Capybara when the methods are inside a `before` block. This works:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "PasswordResets" do
  subject { page }
  describe "it emails user when requesting a password reset" do
    before do
      visit root_path
    end
  end
end
```

This produces the error:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "PasswordResets" do
  subject { page }
  describe "it emails user when requesting a password reset" do
    visit root_path
  end
end
```

This works:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting a password reset" do
    visit root_path
  end
end
```

What I want to do is use the `subject { page }` but be able to use capybara without having to use a `before do end` block. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

I'm on Rails 3.2 with Capybara 1.1.2, Rspec 2.8.1.

Comment: Aren't you required to use either `before(:all)` or `before(:each)`? I didn't think that `before do` by itself was valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't put test code directly in a `describe`. The scope is different. Put it in a `before` or an `it` block.

Comment: seeing that I'm new to Ruby and RoR, would you be kind enough to explain a bit more why this happens, and how scopes/describe blocks work? I'm not being lazy, I just haven't found anything sufficiently "for dummies" to be able to digest...

Comment: Mohamad, I recommend the RSpec book as a good place to start.  The basic basics are that the only thing that goes inside a "describe" block is "before", "context", and "it" blocks